# First Loadtest fails after restart of weblogic server

Tags: java, testing, weblogic, portal

We have encountered a peculiar problem.

If we deploy our application  and then restart the weblogic portal server; and we do a load test, the load test fails with very high response time and low throughput. If we the load test a second time, it runs just fine.

If we just deploy our application, but don't restart the weblogic portal server then the loadtest runs fine.

ANy hints are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the HotSpot JVM warming up - when you restart the server as well, there is just more code to compile. Whenever you're benchmarking or load testing a Java application, it's a good idea to give it a gentle hammering beforehand to get all the code compiled that's going to be compiled. This is particularly true of server applications that will be running for a long time.

Update: I thought I should clarify that of course everything is already compiled to bytecode and I was referring to the JVM's additional compilation in to native code.

Comment: Yes, you've got to compile everything prior to the load test run.  I would suggest some test automation which hits all the pages you will be hitting in your load test.  Selenium, QTP, whatever functional test automation tool you have in house.

Answer (score 0):

there is something that is lazy? tipically servlets are loaded on demand

Answer (score 0):

We are Precompiling while creating the EAR and then all the config params are set to Precompline and also not to recompile and not check if file modified etc.